# jQuery ui combobox add multiple search queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, combobox

I would like to have a drop-down with multiple search queries for one item.

I am using jQuery UI Combobox.

Example: In the drop-down you see 'USD' but if you type 'dollar' it will also show 'USD'

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
      <label>Currency: </label>
      <select id="comboboxCurrency">
         <option></option>
         <option value"dollar">USD</option>
         <option label"dollar">EUR</option>
         <option>AUD</option>
         <option>BRL</option>
         <option>CAD</option>
```

I have tried both 'value' and 'label' both are not working.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using [jQuery widget factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/) to create custom ui for dropdown menu.

You can modify `_source` method of `$.widget` factory in such a way that it will search on the basis of **option value** instead of **option text**

```
_source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
        // get text of the option
        var text = $(this).text();
        // get value of the option
        var value = $(this).val();
        // check is value is set and pass value to matcher.test() method
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(value)))
          return {
            label: text,
            value: text,
            option: this
          };
      }));
    }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $("<span>")
        .addClass("custom-combobox")
        .insertAfter(this.element);

      this.element.hide();
      this._createAutocomplete();
      this._createShowAllButton();
    },

    _createAutocomplete: function() {
      var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

      this.input = $("<input>")
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .val(value)
        .attr("title", "")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,
          source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
        })
        .tooltip({
          classes: {
            "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
          }
        });

      this._on(this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },

        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
      });
    },

    _createShowAllButton: function() {
      var input = this.input,
        wasOpen = false;

      $("<a>")
        .attr("tabIndex", -1)
        .attr("title", "Show All Items")
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo(this.wrapper)
        .button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
          },
          text: false
        })
        .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
        .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
        .on("mousedown", function() {
          wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          input.trigger("focus");

          // Close if already visible
          if (wasOpen) {
            return;
          }

          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
          input.autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    },

    _source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response(this.element.children("option").map(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(value)))
          return {
            label: text,
            value: text,
            option: this
          };
      }));
    },

    _removeIfInvalid: function(event, ui) {

      // Selected an item, nothing to do
      if (ui.item) {
        return;
      }

      // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
      var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
      this.element.children("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
          this.selected = valid = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // Found a match, nothing to do
      if (valid) {
        return;
      }

      // Remove invalid value
      this.input
        .val("")
        .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
        .tooltip("open");
      this.element.val("");
      this._delay(function() {
        this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
      }, 2500);
      this.input.autocomplete("instance").term = "";
    },

    _destroy: function() {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
    }
  });

  $("#comboboxCurrency").combobox();
});
```

```css
.custom-combobox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.custom-combobox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-combobox-input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Currency: </label>
  <select id="comboboxCurrency">
         <option></option>
         <option value = "dollar usd">USD</option>
         <option value = "euro eur">EUR</option>
         <option value = "aud">AUD</option>
         <option value = "brl">BRL</option>
         <option value = "cad">CAD</option>
```